# Windows 10 "Last Accessed" Metadata does not update when I open the file, and says that it was last accessed 30 minutes ago (which I did not)

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, metadata, thumbnails, search-indexing

Windows 10's "Last Accessed" metadata property is very weird. I'd like to just disable it from changing on all the files on my computer completely for archival purposes, and I searched far and wide for an answer but to no avail.

Just now, I was looking for an mp3 file on my computer which prompted me to do several searches in the file explorer on several folders, including my entire D: Drive, which those folders are all in, but I am afraid to open or copy/paste it since it will change its last accessed date, but I wasn't sure if just copying it would change its last accessed date, so I tested it on a text file, wherein I copied it, waited a minute, checked the properties of the original file, and found that its last accessed date had not been changed. This was weird, since I was under the impression that even checking the file's properties would change its last accessed date, but apparently I was wrong. Then I opened the text file, closed it, and checked its properties again, but to my bewilderment the last accessed date still said '1 minute ago', which was how long ago when I created it.

Then I tried checking the properties of another file which I hadn't opened in days, and lo and behold, the last accessed date said '30 minutes ago'. That was probably how long ago it was when I searched for every mp3 file on my drive, so I tried doing it again and opening the same file's properties and still it said that it was last accessed 30 minutes ago. I opened the file, closed it, and then checked again. Still, it said 30 minutes ago.

**TL;DR: With this question, I aim to ask 5 things:**

1. How to "freeze" the Last Accessed date on every file on my computer forever (ie. make it not change when they are opened or modified; a single toggleable setting for this would be great)
2. Why are the Last Accessed dates on my files not updating even when I open them
3. Does searching in File Explorer change the Last Accessed dates on every file it indexes?
4. Does copying a file change its Last Accessed date?
5. Does simply viewing/loading the thumbnail of the file from File Explorer change its Last Accessed date?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I cannot post 5 questions in rapid succession, these questions are all related and my main question is the first one in the list

Comment: Take a look at [this page](https://www.opentechguides.com/how-to/article/windows-10/129/enable-last-access-time.html)